# how to use Net Reactor obfuscation tool to rewrite original file

Tags: net-reactor

When I am using .net Reactor to encrypt my project ,it will create mydllname_secure folder, But i hope Direct rewrite original file, is it possible ?
I have tried to change the settings Target File from

```
<AssemblyLocation>\<AssemblyName>_Secure\<AssemblyFileName>
```

to

```
<AssemblyLocation><AssemblyFileName>
```

but it never encrypted
Please Let me know what change i will do so that same file will be overridden using .net reactor tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following settings worked

```
<AssemblyLocation>\<AssemblyFileName>
```